# vue.js how to call multiple url data in single axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

i am trying get multiple url data in single axios. i already added single url but i want to add another url.

**i tired this but it giving null object error**

{{ BusinessCount }}

{{ UserCount }}

import axios from "axios";
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          businesslists: [],
          Userslist: [],
        };
      },
    
      async asyncData({ $axios }) {
        let { datas } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");
        return {
          Userslist: datas,
        };
      },
    
      computed: {
        UserCount() {
          return Object.keys(this.Userslist).length;
        },
      },
    
      async asyncData({ $axios }) {
        let { data } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
        return {
          businesslists: data,
        };
      },
    
      computed: {
        BusinessCount() {
          return Object.keys(this.businesslists).length;
        },
      },
    };

**i want to show like this**

```
<p>{{ BusinessCount }}</p> 
<p>{{ UserCount }}</p>
```

1st url

```
/Businessregisterlist
```

2nd url

```
/Userlist
```

my code

```
<template>
<p>{{ BusinessCount }}</p>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      BusinessCounts: [],
    };
  },
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    let { datad } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
   return {
      BusinessCounts: datad,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    BusinessCount() {
      return Object.keys(this.BusinessCounts).length;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you want to make another call to the server? Why not copy the line with the first call and change the variable name and URL?

Comment: @Maarten Veerman its giving Object null error

Comment: Where? What? On which line?

Comment: @Maarten Veerman Cannot convert undefined or null to object       return Object.keys(this.BusinessCounts).length;

Comment: But what does thuis have to do with your question about a second URL. Please update the code in your question to match the situation with 2 URLs.

Comment: @Maarten Veerman i updated my tried code please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223213/discussion-between-user12380208-and-maarten-veerman).

Answer (score 0):

In your tried code you define the asyncData function 2 times. That's incorrect. But you can make 2 calls to the server in a single asyncData function.

Try:

```js
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    let { datad } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
    let { dataUsers } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");
   return {
      Businesslist: datad,
      Userslist: dataUsers
    };
  },
computed: {
    BusinessCount() {
      return Object.keys(this.Businesslist).length;
    },
    UserCount() {
      return Object.keys(this.Userslist).length;
    },
  },
```

Make sure you correctly define the `Businesslist` and `Userslist` in the `data` section.

Comment: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "UserCount" is not defined

Comment: Of course you also need to add the computer property. I've updated code example.

Comment: but it giving this error Cannot convert undefined or null to object for  return Object.keys(this.Businesslist).length;